# I want to show 24 month by using date range picker calendar

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

I used this calendar [Date range picker](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) in my web page, And want to show 24 months instead of 2 month.

I use this function  `numberOfMonts: '24'` but it can't work for me. please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/jaydeeep/pen/qBMRwao)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `numberOfMonts` ...surely you should be able to see the problem with that..? Spelling matters in programming

Comment: @CertainPerformance I use `NumberOfMonts: '24'` it is not work for me

Comment: Same problem. Like I said, spelling matters in programming

Comment: but, how will you manage to show 24 months in a single screen for all screen sizes, wouldn't it be a huge ux problem

Comment: @JunaidShaikh i want to show 1 column and inside the scrollbar

Comment: also there isn't any option like 'numberOfMonths' in the official docs, how can you use it

Comment: No they not provide this options, But i want to show 24 months, using hack can we fix?

Comment: well you need to create your own code for this purpose, as daterangepicker doesn't works like that, it replaces the month table from the dom with the next month displayed, so you cannot get more than two months calander at a time with this daterangepicker.

Comment: insight would be appreciated

Comment: In the [link](https://flatpickr.js.org/options/) I found this: the flatpickr may have the function you need `showMonths Integer 1 The number of months to be shown at the same time when displaying the calendar.`

Answer (score 0):

The option `numberOfMonts` is not there in https://www.daterangepicker.com/

Instead daterange picker you can use two date picker controls.

```
<div class="input-group input-daterange col-md-4">
  <input type="text" class="start-date form-control" value="2012-04-05">
  <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
  <input type="text" class="end-date form-control" value="2012-04-19">
</div>
```

something like this

[image]

fiddle: https://codepen.io/ravidevgam/pen/PoYdYeE

Comment: Please read my question care fully. I want to show 24 month in daterange with single input field.

Comment: in that case you need to mod https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to see 24 mini-calendars when you open the picker instead of 2. I think the only way at the moment is to change the library code.

If you open `datarangepicker.js` from the source code you have currently at row 101 the template definition:

```js
options.template =
'<div class="daterangepicker">' +
    '<div class="ranges"></div>' +
    '<div class="drp-calendar left">' +
        '<div class="calendar-table"></div>' +
        '<div class="calendar-time"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="drp-calendar right">' +
        '<div class="calendar-table"></div>' +
        '<div class="calendar-time"></div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="drp-buttons">' +
        '<span class="drp-selected"></span>' +
        '<button class="cancelBtn" type="button"></button>' +
        '<button class="applyBtn" disabled="disabled" type="button"></button> ' +
    '</div>' +
'</div>';
```

and can change it accordingly to have more of that `drp-calendar` divs (so 48 in that specific case).

Then you have to build the calendars, there are the calls at rows 609-610 to `renderCalendar` that go to 619 `renderCalendar: function(side) { ...` and follow the changes, instead of using `this.leftCalendar` and `this.rightCalendar` you could use an array of calendars.

I think it should be doable pretty easily, maybe I would do it parametric with your `numberOfMonths`.

The downside is that you will have to do that all over again every time you update the library. If you plan to update frequently I don't think it isn't even worth the effort to do it on the library and you should do directly a complete custom code. From a brief view to that file it seems there isn't any easy approach to make an injection in the code or extending the methods/classes, there is too much to rewrite to make the calendars general enough.